# How can set language to attribute in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to set language to attribute like this:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        ['name', 'language' => 'ru', 'message' => 'Just enter the Russian.]
    ]
}
```

Comment: You want to show error message in Russian?

Comment: I want to show error message in except Russian.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
       ['name', 'match', 'pattern' => '/[а-ѩA-Ѩ]+$/u', 'message' =>Yii::t('app', 'Just enter Russian') ]
    ]
}
```